# In ES6 how to get object details from one object based other object details

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

There are two files as **questions.jso**n and **answers.json**. The aim is make a summary page which show chosen answers and its question based on `questionID` and `answerValues`, and also with `answerValues` and `values.id`  which in **answers.json**. Is there any option to taking the result in to one variable ?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pj9z6n3r20

My bad practice in React ES6

```
const results = answers.map(answer => {
  console.log(answer)
  return questions.find(question => {
    console.log(question);
    return question.questionID == answer.questionID
  });
});
console.log(results)
```

**Questions.JSON**

```
const questions = [
  {
    questionID: 1,
    title: "Your gender ?",
    values: [{ id: "1", value: "Male" }, { id: "2", value: "Female" }]
  },
  {
    questionID: 2,
    title: "Choose your age ?",
    values: []
  },
  {
    questionID: 3,
    title: "Do you look at a screen within one hour of going to sleep ?",
    values: [{ id: "1", value: "Yes" }, { id: "2", value: "No" }]
  },
  {
    questionID: 4,
    title: "What do you do most time on mobile",
    values: [
      { id: "1", value: "Social media" },
      { id: "2", value: "Play game" },
      { id: "3", value: "Chat" },
      { id: "4", value: "Surf on internet" },
      { id: "5", value: "Call" }
    ]
  },
  {
    questionID: 5,
    title: "On average, how many hours of sleep do you get every night ?",
    values: [
      { id: "1", value: "4-6" },
      { id: "2", value: "7-9" },
      { id: "3", value: "10-11" }
    ]
  },
  {
    questionID: 6,
    title: "Any additional comments or information we should know ?",
    values: []
  }
];
```

**Answers.JSON**

```
const answers = [
  {
    questionID: "1",
    answerValues: "1"
  },
  {
    questionID: "2",
    answerValues: "12"
  },
  {
    questionID: "3",
    answerValues: "1"
  },
  {
    questionID: "4",
    answerValues: ["2", "4"]
  },
  {
    questionID: "5",
    answerValues: "2"
  },
  {
    questionID: "6",
    answerValues: "323123123123"
  }
];
```

Comment: well, first thing you need to realise is that you're not dealing with JSON ... they are just javascript objects. Next thing to realise is that it is you declare `answer` and `question` and try to use `answers` and `questions` in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your advice. I didn't get the second point

Comment: the second point is your var names ... `var question = `, `var answer = ` - but in the code you deal with `questions` and `answers` ... undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX just updated, thanks for you advice

Comment: @Muhammed You can check out my answer and the sandbox. I believe it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/82okp2j630

```
const results = answers.map(answer => {
  // first find the associated question
  let question = questions.find((q) => q.questionID == answer.questionID);
  // since your data structure is either array or string
  let answerValues = (answer.answerValues instanceof Array)? answer.answerValues : [answer.answerValues];

  answerValues = answerValues.map((value) => {
    // grab the object associated with the current answer
    const questionValue = question.values.find((q) => (q.id === value));
    // if there is no associated answer just return the value
    return (questionValue)? questionValue.value : value;
  });
  // return the expected structure used in the React component
  return {
    title: question.title,
    // separate each answer by ,
    value: answerValues.join(", ")
  }
});
```

Then in your React component

```
<h3>{result.title}</h3> Answer: {result.value}

// Results:
/// What do you do most time on mobile
/// Answer: Play game, Surf on internet
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the result of `questions.find`:

```
const results = answers.map(answer => {
  return questions.find(question => {
    return question.questionID == answer.questionID
  })
})
```

If you need some kind of *merge* between boths, my approach would be something like this:

```
const results1 = answers.map((answer) => {
  const question = questions.find(question => question.questionID == answer.questionID)
  return { question: question.title, answer: answer.answerValues }
})
```

And then you'd end up with an array of associated Q&A objects with the following structure:

```
{
  "question": "Choose your age ?",
  "answer": "12"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The answer is nearly there, currently it is getting exact question based on `questionID`. any option to answers in the same way based on `answerValues` ?

Comment: @Muhammed I updated with a quick approach, you can either do that or change the data structure as you please

Comment: The purpose of the function is to show the user, user's selected answer and its question as summary

Comment: Can you give me an example of what `results` should look like?

Comment: Something like **Question: Your gender ? Answer: Male**. like this

Comment: Updated, that seems to be it. You just needed to change the returned object's structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167773/discussion-between-muhammed-and-gmaiolo).